# Find all unimplemented methods in Java interface

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to implement a huge Java interface with lots of methods.

I only had to implement a small part of them: the rest was useless for my context.
So, I am searching a command in IntelliJ to automatically remove all non implemented methods from interface. Does this command exists?

Comment: Can you show what interface you're talking about? Any code would help. Does the interface extend other interfaces? If so, you might be able to extend the parent interface to obtain the method(s) you need.

Comment: This is private work code...

Comment: Then create some sample interfaces like `interface A { }` that accurately represent your code without disclosing anything sensative.

Comment: @Jason To be fair, I don't think a code sample is necessary here. They have an interface with many methods, but it turned out some of those methods aren't actually needed by anyone, and now they're wondering if IntelliJ provides a way to remove all those unneeded methods simultaneously.

Comment: @Slaw, context is very necessary here. If OP has `interface B extends A` which has 2 methods and `interface A` which has 1 method and OP only wants 1 method from interface B then they likely can use polymorphism to get only the methods they want. I.e; `class C implements A {` instead of `class C implements B`. Its very possible there is only 1 interface but without code it's hard to give input.

Comment: @Jason But that's focusing on the implementing class(es). As I understand the question, the OP wants to remove the methods _from the interface_.

Comment: It's possible that the implementing class is an interface as well since an interface can extend another. It's also possible it's a class. It's difficult to determine from just from their text what interface they want to remove the *unused* methods from.

Comment: @Jason Personally, I thought it was clear they want to remove the methods from the declaring interface, making inheritance completely irrelevant. But I suppose this exchange between us is evidence in favor of clarification being required.

Comment: I confirm @Slaw answers

Comment: What about an "Extract Interface" refactoring, to go the other way, from class to interface?  NetBeans has it, maybe IntelliJ IDEA does too...

Comment: Not feasible in my case